# Can the receiver determine the value $r$ from the stealth address?

Tags: stealth-address

The sender generates $r$, can the receiver determine the value $r$ from the stealth address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by stealth address you mean the output one time key, then no, it it not possible. r is the secret key corresponding to the R public key which gets included in the transaction. The recipient will use that public key only, and never learn r, using the fact that aR == rA.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only the sender knows `r` and the sender would only use/persist `r` to later prove a payment made. The receiver cannot derive `r`, which is a random scalar created by the sender and used as the point multiplier on the receivers public view key.

A great article on stealth addresses can be found [here](https://steemit.com/monero/@luigi1111/understanding-monero-cryptography-privacy-part-2-stealth-addresses).